# DISTINCT as a clause or a function

Tags: mysql, sql

I was doing some experiments with the `DISTINCT` keyword and some particular situations caught up my attention.

First of all I noticed that I can put some parenthesis with `DISTINCT`, for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(NAME) FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

is ok, while

```
SELECT DISTINCT(NAME, SURNAME) FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

gives me an error. Why?

And what's the sense of allowing operations like this one?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(NAME), COUNT(SURNAME) FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

Comment: " what's the sense of allowing operations like this one?" there isn't any. Standard SQL wouldn't allow `SELECT NAME, COUNT(SURNAME) FROM EMPLOYEE;` with or without `DISTINCT`

Comment: `(NAME)` equals `NAME`; it's a column name where you added superfluous parentheses. This is allowed, because you can use parentheses around expressions for readability or operator precedence (as in `(a = 1 or b = 2) and c = 3`). `NAME, SURNAME` however ist not an expression, so using parentheses around them results in a syntax error.

Comment: And `SELECT DISTINCT(NAME), COUNT(SURNAME) FROM EMPLOYEE;` really makes no sense at all. It is only allowed, because you are not in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode, thus telling the DBMS that you perfectly know what you are doing, but it seems you don't :-) The query gives you one result line containing an arbitrarily picked name from the table plus the number of non-null surnames in the table. Then you apply `DISTINCT` on that one row :-| I suggest you set your DBMS to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode until you master row aggregation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DISTINCT` (or `DISTINCTROW`) is not a function; it is an option of the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) statement that tells MySQL to strip duplicate rows from the resultset generated by the query. By default it returns all the generated rows, including the duplicates.

It can also be used together with [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) aggregate function (as [`COUNT(DISTINCT expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)) and it has the same meaning: it ignores the duplicates.

Because `DISTINCT` is not a function, `DISTINCT(NAME)` is interpreted as `DISTINCT` followed by the expression `(NAME)` (which is the same as `NAME`).

`SELECT DISTINCT(NAME, SURNAME) FROM EMPLOYEE` doesn't work because `(NAME, SURNAME)` is not a valid MySQL expression.

Answer (score 4):

`DISTINCT` is nothing really -- more of a modifier.  It is used in two places.  It can modifier aggregation functions.  The only one worth using is `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

In your case, you are using it as a modifier to `SELECT`.  It simply says that each *entire* row should be distinct.

So, when you say:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT (name, surname)
```

This is the same as getting all distinct rows of `(name, surname)` from this query:

```
SELECT (name, surname)
```

MySQL does not recognize this syntax.  In some databases, this represents a tuple or row constructor.  But, because MySQL does not recognize this syntax, you are getting an error.

As a note:  `SELECT DISTINCT` can be quite powerful but it is often not necessary.  More typically, you can do a `GROUP BY` with the column you actually want "distinct"ed.  For instance:

```
SELECT name, surname, COUNT(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY name, surname
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

This query actually shows the duplicates and how often they occur.